# What would be an efficient way to write a program in C (or just an algorithm), to Search and replace characters in a file?

Tags: c, file-io, text-processing, replace

the user will provide 2 string at run-time such as "asdf" "qwer",
now every occurrence of 'a' should be replaced by 'q', 's' by 'w', 'd' by 'e' and 'f' by 'r'
the length of string may vary.
now the point is the file to be operated on is huge, 3-4 terabytes,so we need an efficient program of an efficiency of "n" or "n(log(n))", a sequence of if...else wont help.
hints given are:
1.>the file has no special characters or white spaces. It just consists of LOWER CASE characters
2.>the program should use the fact that there are only 26 characters in the file.
3.>finally the solution is someway done using the ascii values of the characters.

Additional Details
File is supposed to be a thesis on a person,so its not a sequence.
and ya we have to read the whole file sequentially,the only thing that should not be done is a comparison for every character,that is if(a)then(q)elseif(s)then(w)....somethin… more efficient???

Please help

Comment: What kinds of data structures are allowed?

Comment: @R.. this aint any homework,its a question asked in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array at the beginning of the program containing 26 characters. Then replace the ones you want in this array. Then parse the whole file replacing every characters with your table values.

```
char charsToReplace = "asdf";
char replaceBy = "qwer";
charsToReplaceCount = 4;

char replaceTable[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', ... , 'z'}

for (int i=0; i<charsToReplaceCount; ++i)
{
    replaceTable[charsToReplace[i] - 'a'] = replaceBy[i];
}

...

for (int i=0; i<fileLengthChunk; ++i)
{
    file[i] = replaceTable[file[i] - 'a'];
}
```

I've skipped read and write of the file as well as the chunking since file is huge.

Answer (score 0):

You'd start by searching for the first character in the 'to be replaced' string, once you found an instance you start working through your 'to be replaced' string checking each subsequent character, if a complete match is found then you make the replacement.

If the strings are not always the same length, you are going to need to read the file in and write the modified file out? I'd suggest that this would be done in chunks, unless you can host 4TB in memory.

The basic pseudo code would be:

```
objectstr = "asdf";
targetstr = "qwer";
while not eof
{
   filechar = readchar;
   if (filechar == objectstr[0])
   {
      if (remainingfilechars > length(objectstr)-1)
      {
          match = true;
          for i = 1 to length(objectstr)-1
          {
              filechar = readchar
              if (filechar != objectstr[i])
              {
                  match = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (match)
          {
              writefile(targetstr);
          }
          else
          {
              fileseek(currentfileposition - (length(objectstr)-1));
              writefile(filechar);
          }
       }
    }
    else
    {
        writefile(filechar);
    }
}
```